# When logging in it is not taking me to the correct location

Tags: php, html, css, sql

Using PHP I am trying to check whether the user is an admin or a normal user. If they are a normal user then it should redirect them to home.php. However if they are an admin then it should redirect them to admin.php. When entering in the username and password of a standard user it sends me to home.php which is what is expected. However whenever I use an admin login it does not direct me to admin.php. Instead it redirects me to authentication.php which is the script that checks if the username and password are correct.

I have tried 2 different blocks of code, the first one did not work at all as it came up with syntax errors. However this one should work fine but it does not. I have also checked if the correct numbers are being stored within the database. 1 being a standard user and 2 being for an admin. I have printed the admin level on my profile page so I know that it is storing the data properly.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {
           if ($_SESSION['admin'] === "2") {
        header('Location: admin.php');
    } else {
        header('Location: home.php');
    }
} else {
    header('Location: home.php');
}
```

I expect that when an admin logs in it should direct me to admin.php, however I am just being directed to a blank screen of authentication.php.

Comment: You should normally put `exit;` after a `header()` call, Not sure if this changes anything.

Comment: Does not change anything.

Comment: None of the code shown here would redirect you to authentication.php. I would assume the issue is somewhere else

Comment: P.s. is the code you've shown above actually part of the authentication.php script? Because another reason you might see a white screen is if PHP has crashed, and error reporting is not switched on

Comment: exactly, @adyson you are right. there is no redirection rule which is redirecting to authentication.php however i think either he wrote it wrong it is home.php but he wrote it authentication.php or he has another redirection code on home.php file where he redirecting to authentication.php from home.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is accurate. Forexample

```
<?php
$_SESSION['admin'] = "2";
if (isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {
           if ($_SESSION['admin'] === "2") {
        header('Location: admin.php');
    } else {
        header('Location: home.php');
    }
} else {
    header('Location: home.php');
}
?>
```

If you run this on localhost it redirects to admin.php page properly.  as you are using === so you have to make sure your datatype is matched.

for example:

```
<?php

$a = "1";

if ($a === 1) {
echo "not ok";  
}

if ($a == 1) {
echo "ok";  
}

if ($a === "1") {
echo "This time ok";    
}

if ($a == "1") {
echo "it's also ok";    
}
?>
```

First echo doesnt show as if cant matched datatype. so i suggest you to change === to == and see. hopefully it will solve your problem

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {
               if ($_SESSION['admin'] == "2") {
            header('Location: admin.php');
exit();
        } else {
            header('Location: home.php');
exit();
        }
    } else {
        header('Location: home.php');
exit();
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return the link page from the php script like below:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {
    $data['admin_page_link'] = 'admin.php';
    echo json_encode($data);
}else {
    $data['home_page_link'] = 'home.php';
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Then just call it in javascript ajax call to redirect to the desired page:

```
if (response.user === 'admin') {
            window.location.href = response.admin_page_link;
} else {
            window.location.href = response.home_page_link;;
}
```

In the above code you may check by using the full web address of php file like: http://localhost/admin.php